# Writing a function for the term structure of Exposure

Tags: r

I have a data frame (lets call it `credit`) that has a column named `OutstandingBal`, `InterestRate` and `LoanTenor` which I would like to model the term structure for a maximum period of 40 years for each observation in the data frame. So I want my data frame to have 40 additional columns showing this term structure according to a certain formula.

I am using the following formula but its giving me an object, `EAD` in the Global Environment with `NULL(Empty)`,

```
max_tenor <- 0:40
EAD <- for (i in max_tenor) {
  EAD = ifelse(credit$LoanTenor<i,credit$OutstandingBal*(1+credit$InterestRate)^(4/12)-credit$OutstandingBal/credit$LoanTenor,0)
  return(EAD)}
```

May you kindly assist where I am going wrong? Hopefully my query is clear

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives you back `NULL` because you are assigning `EAD`, the result from a `for` loop which is always `NULL`
On the other hand,  `return` inside a `for loop` stops the execution so it will stop at the first iteration.

I think you want something like this:

```
max_tenor <- 0:40
    for (i in max_tenor) {
      EAD[[i+1]] <- ifelse(credit$LoanTenor<i,credit$OutstandingBal*(1+credit$InterestRate)^(4/12)-credit$OutstandingBal/credit$LoanTenor,0)
      }
```

It will give you a list, each element of the list stores an iteration of your `ifelse`

Other options could be the `apply` family. For instance:

```
EAD <- sapply(max_tenor,function(i) ifelse(credit$LoanTenor<i,credit$OutstandingBal*(1+credit$InterestRate)^(4/12)-credit$OutstandingBal/credit$LoanTenor,0))
```

Comment: thanks both solutions work but I prefer the second one